# How to show/hide shared _Layout.cshtml element according of user roles

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have shared _Layout.cshtml like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Студентска служба", "Index", "Students", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Студентски програми", "Index", "Studies")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Референти", "Index", "Referents")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Пријава испита", "Index", "Exams")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In DataBase I have 3 type of users (admin, referent and student).

Here is my UsersControler:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private StudentServiceContext db = new StudentServiceContext();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
    
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Users user)
    {
        using (StudentServiceContext db = new StudentServiceContext())
        {
            var usr = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            if (usr != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                Session["Password"] = usr.UserName.GetHashCode();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Referents");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", " Нетачно корисничко име или лозинка!");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoggedIn()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

So, for example if Loged user isn-t student, I want to hide

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Пријава испита", "Index", "Exams")</li>
```

I tried by using @model dynamic and @model StudentService.Models.Users, so I thoght I could use
if condition, like @if(Model.UserRole.Equals("student")), etc but nothing works propertly...

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Try this:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("student")) {
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Пријава испита", "Index", "Exams")</li>
}
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I already tried that way, but it's hiden no matter what is role of loged user.

Comment: So have you verified that the User has the role student and that 'student' is the actual name of your role?